# Scrapy not making requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I may be doing something wrong, I am trying to learn so I used a code to scrape something really simple as 'Youtube' just to see if it works.

```
import scrapy

class TesteSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name= "teste"

    def start_request(self):
        url='http://www.youtube.com'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title::text').extract()
        with open('informacao', 'w') as f:
            f.write(title)
        self.log('saved file successfully')
```

And then when I run my spider with

```
scrapy crawl teste
```

the spider runs but it seem to just open and then finish the spider.

Reading the input below there isn't any Get requests.

```
    2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.1.1.0, libxml2 2.9.7, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.3.1, w3lib 1.18.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) - [GCC 5.4.0 20160609], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017), cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Linux-4.10.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 6, 12, 6, 38, 572007),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 52027392,
 'memusage/startup': 52027392,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 6, 12, 6, 38, 565527)}
2018-01-06 10:06:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

When I run

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.youtube.com'
```

I have no problems

Comment: The name of the method is `start_requests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stranac mentioned in the comment:

> The name of the method is start_requests

you can revise you code and try again